# How to write a dynamic django orm queryset based on the filters passed?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset

i need to apply filters dynamically on a queryset depending on the filters passed as a json from the front end.

for ex.

if json passed is : { id:[1,2,3] }
then queryset will be : Model.objects.filter(id__in=id)

if json is passed as: { id:[1,2,3],country:['india','australia'] }

then queryset will be : Model.objects.filter(id__in=id,country__in=country)

how to achieve this dynamically?

Comment: use `if esle` detect json and change query like what you want in `queryset`

Comment: for N filters there will be N **ifs** which is not a correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an if/else statement to detect if the country list is empty:

```
if not country:
     Model.objects.filter(id__in=id)
else:
     Model.objects.filter(id__in=id, country__in=country)
```

**Edit:**

A comment pointed out that the amount of filters are dynamic. So in Django `.filter()` returns another `QuerySet` and Querysets are lazily evaluated, meaning [they can be chained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters) and be used in a loop.

So using [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (`**`), we can compose the `kwargs` to pass to `.filter()`.

Because the exact datatype/schema of the filters is not provided, I will use a dictionary as example, `filter_dictionary`. In this dictionary the `key` is the filter that will be used and the `value` will be a list.

```
# Compose first Queryset
qs = Model.objects.all()

# Loop over dictionary
for key, value in filter_dictionary.items():

    # Use unpacking to compose kwarg
    qs.filter(**{'{0}__in'.format(key): value})

# do something with the QuerySet
```

Comment: there can be N filters passed, so if-else is not a correct approach.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar please clarify the question on this mattter then, also, could you add the View/Serializer as context for the question?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a django_filters

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters    

class ContentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    id = filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr="in")
    country = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="in")

    class Meta:
        model = <your_model>
        fields = ['id', 'country']
```

Then add to your view class

```
filterset_class = ContentFilter
```